# SQL Select only members that have all 3 degrees

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables. `Tourist` table, `Junction` table, and `Country` table.
They're all linked by foreign key.
    `Junction` table has `tourist_id` and `country_id`
    `Country` table has `name` (name of the country)

Junction links Tourist and Country by `tourist_id` and `country_id`

I would like to retrieve all information of `tourist` that has been to strictly all of only `Japan`, `Taiwan`, and `Canada`.

If a tourist has been to more or less than those 3 countries, I don't want them to be returned.

How can I write this SQL query?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
select j.tourist_id
from junction j join
     country c
     on j.country_id = c.country_id
group by j.tourist_id
having count(distinct case when c.name in ('Japan', 'Canada', 'Taiwan') then c.name end) = 3 and
       sum( (c.name not in ('Japan', 'Canada', 'Taiwan'))::int ) = 0;
```